# SSH into server Authentication Failed

Tags: azure, ssl, ssh

Hi I 'm trying to SSH into a server from client (RHEL7) machine. I already added the clients public key (id_rsa.pub) to the servers `authorized_keys` file. I *also* added the servers fingerprint to my clients `known_hosts` file. When I try sshing, I used the `-vvv` flag to get some debug info and this is what I got (of course I put a fake IP in, and the returned SHA256 is fake):

```
[azure@blahblah ssh]$ ssh -v myusername@10.22.11.111
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.22.11.111 [10.22.11.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/azure/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/azure/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/azure/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/azure/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/azure/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/azure/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/azure/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/azure/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_1.1.5
debug1: no match: Sun_SSH_1.1.5
debug1: Authenticating to 10.22.11.111:22 as 'suser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:aaaaaaaabbbbbbbccccccdddeeefffff
debug1: Host '10.22.11.111' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/azure/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1001)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1001)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/azure/.ssh/id_rsa
Authentication failed.
```

Can anyone provide some insight on what I can do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permission issue in .ssh folder
Following commands to be run at the server to set the correct permission for the folders.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: the .ssh folder is already 700 and the authorized keys are all 644......